# Using mat-select in a Custom Element (web component) opens options outside the shadow DOM

Tags: angular, angular-material, custom-element

When using a mat-select element in my custom element the options are shown outside the created shadow dom in HTML that means the options are not shown right below the select control.

As far as I figured out I need to set ViewEncapsulation to ShadowDom. Only this way my custom element worked in all browsers. So the solution to my problem should be using ShadowDom.

```
Component({
  selector: 'app-survey',
  templateUrl: './survey.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./survey.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})

<mat-form-field #ff>
    <mat-select placeholder="Auswahl ERP System" [(ngModel)]="erpSystem">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let choice of erpSystemAuswahl" [value]="choice">
                {{choice}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I expect the options shown right with the select element. How to I change the behaviour of the options to be shown correctly?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what the problem is. DOM structure and screen position (DOM layout) are different concepts that are largely independent of each other. The `mat-option` elements should not have to be inside shadow DOM to appear in the proper position relative to a select field that is inside shadow DOM. Please share code - ideally a working Stackblitz example.

Comment: @G.Tranter thank you for your question for clarification. Because the problem only shows up when implementing it in a custom element I don't know how to show this using a Stackblitz example. Please be aware that the problem only occurs only when using the mat-select component in a custom element.

Comment: Try turning off shadow DOM in your web component to see if the shadow DOM is really part of the equation or not. Also, if you can't create a stackblitz - then post your web component code. What you posted is merely a simple example that isn't the problem so it doesn't help by itself.

Comment: @G.Tranter I did try different ViewEncapsulations (Native, ShadowDom,...) the problem existed with any setting. 
I uploaded the whole project to Stackblitz but as I wrote before it cannot run properly in Stackblitz but you could download the project locally and run it. I uploaded the project here: https://github.com/ThomasEnioKohler/survey

Comment: I have the same problem now, did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: @ArthurKovacs I didn't find a solution to this problem until now

Comment: @ThomasKohler - I ended up loading the material css file where I'm using the web component. That is because the overlay from the material dropdowns will attach to the host's body, and not the shadow dom's. It works like that for me.

Answer (score 0):

Elements use <slot> as the target for content projection, not ng-content, so when the options are being projected into the <mat-select> it cannot find anywhere to project them into and adds them directly after the </mat-select> instead.

Apart from asking the Angular Material team to add slots I'm not sure what you can do. I'm busy trying to add slots dynamically to material components using directives (not sure it will work)